# What does Ghidra mean by ._0_3_?

Tags: ghidra, decompiler

What does `._0_3_` mean in the Ghidra decompiler?

```
my_string[0]._0_3_ = CONCAT12(DAT_14123b1f6,DAT_14123b1f4);
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to check the relevant disassembly and retype variable

this is basically due to size difference between variable (truncation , casting ) etc

[image]

in the screenshot above uvar15 is a ULONGLONG a64 bit register R9:8 as shown in popup
so uVar2 inherits the type

in the next line uVar2 is casted as 32 bit (uint) and orred with another 32bit entity

and stored on the lower half of 64 bit register

this is denoted in the decompiler result as `uVar15._0_4_`

this can also happen  if a struct member type is accessed or a byte in a char array is accessed

`mystring[0]._0_3_` is doing something on the 3rd( byte ,char  , xxx ) of a type of some array

check your disassembly ,split the variable ,retype the variable for clarity

## edit

post relevant disassembly de-compilation results without accompanying disassembly does not help

basically concat 12 is concatenating 1byte + 2byte from specified locations

so it is a total of 3 bytes
the three bytes are stored in least three bytes of a ptr  mystring[0]

assume rcx = "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00"  at start
concat12(x,y)  takes one char from x and two chars from y and combines them
'a'+'bc'  == {61 62 63}as hex
and rcx is made to be "00 00 00 00 00 61 62 63"  at end

then the operation on the Least three byte are indicated by the suffix **.*0_3***

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand your answer enough to ask for clarification. I still don't understand what `._0_3_` means?

Comment: i tried to clarify further but doing this without relevant disassembly isn't fun

Comment: Aha so am I understanding correctly that `._0_3` refers to the least three bytes?

Comment: post disassembly without that this is mere guesswork